# WPF rewrite static DataTemplate to dynamically version

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to ask somebody for solve of my problem with dynamic rewrite datatemplate

I have prepare DataTemplate

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="pictureTemplate"> 
       <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Image">                   
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="180" />                        
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="120" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
            </Style>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>           
        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Location}" />            
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

and then I have itemcotrol with:

```
<ItemsControl Name="itemscontrol2"  Visibility="Hidden"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PicturesRight}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource pictureTemplate}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource panelTemplate2}" local:DragDropHelper.IsDragSource="true" />
```

And everything work fine. But I would like to rewrite this code to dynamic version, because I need change value of property `Width` and `Height`.

I have prepared this section od code:

```
DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate(typeof(ItemsControl));
var style = new Style(typeof(Image));
var setter = new Setter()
{
    Property = Control.WidthProperty,
    Value = 200.0
};

style.Setters.Add(setter);

var setter1 = new Setter()
{
    Property = Control.HeightProperty,
    Value = 150.0
};

style.Setters.Add(setter1);

dt.Resources.Add(typeof(Image), style);
itemscontrol2.ItemTemplate = dt;
```

But this code doesnt work. I dont know what the problem is but I have tried everything possible.
Can anyone help me in solving this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: why not you opt for binding the dynamic properties. to write a template in code behind may require you to use factory classes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing DataTemplate in code do it in resource section as follows

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Temp1">
        <TextBlock Text="1"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Temp2">
        <TextBlock Text="2"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<ItemsControl Name="itemscontrol2" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Temp1}" Foreground="White" ItemsSource="{Binding Lista}"/>
```

to change in C#

```
itemscontrol2.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["Temp2"];
```

Why don't you use something like this to resize dynamically

```
 <Grid Background="CadetBlue">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ItemsControl Name="control" ItemsSource="{Binding Lista}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="2.jpg"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <Button Content="Change" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Yes, its possible. But I need dynamic change (based on the window size) width and height of image. I did not understand from your example if its possible change this properties.

Comment: You can make your DataTemplate dependent from widt/height. Explain precisely what you mean to acquire.

Comment: I'm new in WPF and I need change size of image inside itemscontrol dependet on actual size of my wpf window. I thought that just create new datatemplate as I have described above, but this code doesnt work and I do not understand your example :-)

Comment: When your window is enlarged your image inside datatemplate is supposed to do the same?